# Poco DOM Writer stops writing when umlaut appears

Tags: xml, encoding, poco-libraries

I want to create a XML File with Poco::XML::DOMWriter.
But if inside a Node is an Umlaut (ä,ö,ü etc) the Writer stops the writing of the XML File.

This is working example:

```
int main() {

    AutoPtr<Document> pDoc = new Document;
    AutoPtr<Element> pRoot = pDoc->createElement("root");

    AutoPtr<Element> pElement = pDoc->createElement("Element");
    AutoPtr<Text> pText = pDoc->createTextNode("Example text");

    AutoPtr<Element> pElement1 = pDoc->createElement("Element1");
    AutoPtr<Text> pText2 = pDoc->createTextNode("Text with umlaut: Übermorgen gibt es Regen");

    AutoPtr<Element> pElement2 = pDoc->createElement("Element2");
    AutoPtr<Text> pText3 = pDoc->createTextNode("Text without");

    pElement->appendChild(pText);
    pElement1->appendChild(pText2);
    pElement2->appendChild(pText3);

    pRoot->appendChild(pElement);
    pRoot->appendChild(pElement1);
    pRoot->appendChild(pElement2);

    pDoc->appendChild(pRoot);


    DOMWriter writer;
    UTF8Encoding utf8Enc;
    writer.setNewLine("\n");
    writer.setEncoding("UTF-8", utf8Enc);
    writer.setOptions(Poco::XML::XMLWriter::PRETTY_PRINT);
    writer.writeNode("D:\\test.xml", pDoc);

}
```

If I debug this code the `pDoc` Variable contains the whole `XML` Structure I had defined.

But on the Filesystem the XML File does only contains this:

```
<root>
    <Element>Example text</Element>
    <Element1>Text with umlaut:
```

The second element was not written completely and the last Element is missing.

How do I configure the `DOMWriter` to support special keys?
The XML should look like these:

```
<root>
    <Element>Example text</Element>
    <Element1>Text with umlaut: Übermorgen gibt es Regen</Element1>
    <Element2>Text without</Element2>
</root>
```